# Not able to get irb console working with tumblr_client gem

Tags: ruby, oauth, tumblr

I have very little experience with APIs which is something that I'm trying to change so I'm trying to get started with the Tumblr api.  I've installed the tumblr_client gem ([documentation here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tumblr_client/0.8.5)) and am following the instructions.  I've created an application on a new Tumblr account and have the necessary OAuth information (consumer_key, consumer_secret, ect.)  Actually getting it to do something is proving difficult, so like a good little programmer I'm trying to get the console going to explore a bit.

This requires a bit of setup, so I'm following the instructions here:

> The first time that you go to use the irb console, if you have no
>   .tumblr file, it will walk you through the process of generating one.
>   You will be prompted for your consumer_key and consumer_secret (which
>   you can get here: http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/register) and then sent
>   out to the site to verify your account. Once you verify, you will be
>   redirected to your redirect URL (localhost by default) and copy the
>   oauth_verifier back into the console. Then you're all set!

I'm prompted for my key and secret, then I go to the URL where I'm supposed to give authorization.  Tumblr gives me a popup which reads "Is it alright for this application to access some of your data and make posts to your account? You are logged in as example@example.com" and the options to cancel or allow.  I hit allow and it just takes me into the account itself, at no point am I ever given any kind of verification code that I can put in to get the console working.

At this point I'm stuck and can't go any further so I'm activating the network.  Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify a redirect or callback url at any point in the oauth config process? It's probably done on tumblr's API website. This url would be your app's endpoint to which Tumblr sends a request to with the user's data. By the way, oauth can sometimes be confounding to set up. You won't be able to use `localhost` as a callback url, for example, though you can get a temporary domain name with a free local tunneling app.

*edit* To go into more detail on some of these points ...

- **callback url**: To reiterate, this cannot be localhost. Setting the correct callback url will get you unstuck from your current predicament. Instead of redirecting to the tumblr homepage, you want the confirmation page to redirect to your app. Anyway, I think you're totally sensible to want to test it out before you deploy. But unless you deploy or use a local tunnel, your local application doesn't actually have a URL that can be reached from anywhere except your computer.
- **local tunnelling services**: [ngrok](http://ngrok.com), [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me). To give an example with ngrok: Say you have a Rails server running on port 3000. Then in another terminal you run `ngrok 3000` and you get a url which exposes your local server to the real internet. Note that this changes every time you restart ngrok (unless you pay them). In your application, you should make a unique route for the callback. Say you have a route which matches `/oauth_callback` to the `oauth_callback` controller action. Then the route you'd provide as your callback url would be `http://MY_CUSTOM_NAME.ngrok.com/oauth_callback`.
- **The controller action**: I don't specifically know how Tumblr sends user data to the callback. Perhaps the information is in the headers or maybe it's in the body. It might be JSON or XML. Whatever it is, you can explore the data by placing a breakpoint in your controller action. You can inspect the `params`, `headers`, etc. I'd expect that they'd give you some token credentials and probably a user name/email as well.

Comment: I understand some of what you said, mainly the part about OAuth being confounding :).  Tumblr asks for an "Application Website" which I set to localhost and a "Default callback URL" which I set to a forward slash not having any idea what else to do.  It seems as if Tumblr expects you to have an application already deployed and running before you can do anything with their API which strikes me as difficult.  I've never heard about local tunneling applications, can you elaborate, and perhaps point me in the direction of a good one (or good tutorial?)  Oh, and thanks, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @JonathonNordquist see the updated answer and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Max, the additional information was amazingly helpful.  You'll forgive me if I gush like a schoolgirl but OMG!  This is. So.  Cool!  I had no idea that services like this even existed, much less how to use them.  This is a great tool for my belt, you've not only helped solve my problem, you've made me a better developer.  If you're ever in the Midwest, drop me a line and I'll buy you a beer.