# How to connect to an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom

I know this is probably a very basic question, but i'm having some serious trouble. I have developed a rails "wellness" application and the final step is connecting to this -- https://www.humanapi.co

I'm attempting to follow the web guide here http://hub.humanapi.co/docs/connect-web-guide

Unfortunately I am getting stuck on this part

> "The specified options.finish callback will need to POST the sessionTokenObject to your server. To finalize the user authentication flow you will POST the sessionTokenObject signed with your clientSecret to our servers. Read more about this process below.
>
> Refresh/Redirect on finish()
>
> After you POST the sessionTokenObject to your server, you must redirect the user or refresh the current page with the publicToken data so that the Human Connect button will open in Edit Mode described below.
>
> Human Connect will continue polling our servers after it is closed until you refresh the page. This is correct behavior and necessary for security reasons, despite a 412 response that may be seen in the javascript console."

It says to POST the sessionTokenObject to my server... I'm running this on my local machine, so what server would that be? Then it says to

"POST the sessionTokenObject signed with your clientSecret to our servers"

How would I go about doing that in rails?

There is a gem here that is supposed to connect to the api https://github.com/HealthHero/humanapi

i've read through the documentation but i'm unsure of /exactly/ how to implement it and grab the token.

I'm sorry if this is a lot to ask, but i'm new to rails and web development in general. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36379160/2981429) to another question that is relevant here, but to comment on your specific situation -

You are correct that you won't be able to receive a callback POST if your application is running locally. A solution is to use a "local tunneling service" like ngrok or localtunnel.

Once you get the callback POST, you'll probably have an access token you can use for the API. You might still need to write code for refreshing access tokens, depending on the requirements of the API your using.

In general I recommend using a gem whenever possible to interact with APIs, but not all of them support oAuth.